# Abrir Aplicación Heroku me da ERROR

Tags: heroku

he seguido los pasos del video para hacer Ninghtscout y el el paso de abrir la aplicación me da error, he metido el MONGO_CONNECTION modificado, no se donde viene el problema.
Muchas gracias de antemano.
Un saludo.